# Just doing a new Rails app. Using Devise. Would like to have one more column for the user table: timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This would allow me to use it in displaying time information...

Should I just keep it separate from the devise stuff?  Or is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a migration, add_timezone_to_users.

And inside def self.up write add_column :users,:timezone,

Answer (score 2):

Just add another column to your User model for storing the user's timezone in.